Using Scrapy to Scrape an API via a Client
I am making a project that will use PyGithub, which is a well-typed GitHub API client, with Scrapy to extract metadata from GitHub. The user interface looks like:
from github import Github, Auth

import os

client = Github(auth=Auth.Token(os.environ.get("GITHUB_TOKEN"))

# get an organization (scrape 0)
org = client.get_organization('myorg')

# get its repositories (scrape 1)
repos = org.get_repos()

for repo in repos:
  # get issues for the repository (scrape 2)
  issues = repo.get_issues()

  for issue in issues:
    # do things
    pass

  # get pull requests for the repository (scrape 3)
  pulls = repo.get_pulls()

  for pull in pulls:
    # do things
    pass

I know that Scrapy is primarily built around raw HTTP requests, but I do need the concurrency that it offers so I can do this fairly quickly rather than serially.
What components do I need to replace to have Scrapy work with an API client and API objects instead of HTTP? I have been trying to replace regular middleware, downloader middleware, requests, responses, and it seems to need certain attributes that it won't work without.

The Scrapy request concurrency is possible because the Twisted's HTTP client is asynchronous, if you omit it you either lose the request concurrency or need to reimplement it from scratch.
(the components you need to replace are the download handlers for HTTP and HTTPS, see scrapy-playwright)
